# Prevent content on the page from moving while width page is less 1350 px

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to prevent content on the page from moving, resizing while width page is under 1350 px. Min-width doesn't work for this.. so what can i do ?

Btw on my css code, for the `width, height, transformation: translate`, i'm using the value `vmax` , and not `px` or `%`. So the `min-width` maybe doesn't work with it, because, when i resize my page, i see that the container div is stuck at 1200px, but my elements in it keep resizing because they are using `vmax`, so they just adapt there size with the window size too.. :(

I putted all of my html code on a div container and i did this :

```
.container {
    min-width: 1350px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

But still don't work..

The code + preview : https://plnkr.co/edit/4BizatqN0GkGc7nedoBF?p=preview

(**I'm trying to stop resizing the three white rectangle when my browser width is under 1350px...**)

Comment: You can use @media(max-width: 1350px) { .container {width: 10px}}. Media queries are essential for mobile first development. Try everything you can to familiarize yourself with them. When making a web app, you'll want to start with a small screen with media queries and work your way up to bigger screens. Easier to manage that way. Hope this helped.

Comment: I added the `@media(max-width: 1350px) { .container {width: 10px}}` but it still doesn't work, the three white rectangle keep shrinking themselves.. :( @joshbang

Comment: Do you have any inline styling in your html? That could be blocking it.

Comment: Just saw your plunkr. I'll look at it. one sec

Comment: I see the problem. You don't actually want to edit he "container" class. You want to focus on the IDs for the rectangles. I'll put an answer down in like 3 minutes when I redo the css

Comment: Thank you very much man, i appreciate ! @joshbang

Comment: Did that answer end up working? If not, I can help troubleshoot

Comment: Your question should have a minimal viable set of code in the question that replicates the issue rather than asking us to debug a large set of code in some linked place that may go away - basically enlisting us to debug is not the best method to asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#tabcmp0 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6vmax;
    left: 15.25vmax;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

#tabcmp1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6vmax;
    left: 43.25vmax;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

#tabcmp2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6vmax;
    left: 71.25vmax;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

// Media queries go at the bottom of your css files
 @media(min-width: 1350px) {
    #tabcmp0 {

      width: 27vmax; // pick custom widths and heights
      height: 43vmax;

  }

  #tabcmp1 {

      width: 27vmax;
      height: 43vmax;

  }

  #tabcmp2 {

      width: 27vmax;
      height: 43vmax;

  }
}
```

Keep in mind, you will have to edit other stuff to make it look natural now. But you have the means to do it yourself now :) I went with min width instead of max width on this example.

Remember to put the media queries at the BOTTOM of your css files.

Comment: Hello again and thanks for the help @joshbang, but it seems like it does not work. When I resize my page (when it is less than 1350 pixels), it continues to resize :( By the way, I'm working on Mozilla Firefox if it can help.

Comment: The final result that i want is simply, when the browser is equal or less than 1350px, i want to stop resizing **ALL OF THE ELEMENTS** on the page, and only use the scrollbar to deplace on the page. @joshbang

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, very simple solution

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1350px) {
    div[id^="tabcmp"] { min-width: 364px;}
}
```

---